# why is MySQL casting varchar as integer when WHERE clause is present?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database table, `student_import_record`, with a `student_id varchar(50)` field that can contain alphanumeric data.

When I run this `SELECT` statement:

```
select student_id from student_import_record;
```

I get the `VARCHAR` results as expected:

```
0001546
0001660
0002207
0002349
```

But when I run this `SELECT` statement with a `WHERE` clause:

```
select student_id from student_import_record where student_import_id = 185;
```

I get results that appear to be cast as an integer:

```
1546
1660
2207
2349
```

How do I prevent this casting when using a `WHERE` clause?

Full Table schema:

`mysql> describe student_import_record;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| student_id         | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| relationship       | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_of_birth      | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| first_name         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| gender             | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| student_type       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phone              | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address2           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state              | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| zip                | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mandate            | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ssn                | varchar(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| suffix             | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| department         | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| benefit1           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| benefit2           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| benefit3           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| benefit4           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| benefit5           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| benefit6           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| plan1              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| plan2              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| plan3              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| plan4              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| plan5              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| plan6              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| account            | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| enrollment_config  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| imported_at        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status             | smallint(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status_description | longblob     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| student_import_id  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |`

Result sets

mysql> select student_id from student_import_record where student_import_id = 185 limit 10;

`+------------+
| student_id |
+------------+
| 1546       |
| 1660       |
| 2207       |
| 2349       |
| 3123       |
| 3208       |
| 3319       |
| 3811       |
| 3837       |
| 3842       |
+------------+`

10 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select student_id from student_import_record limit 10;

`+------------+
| student_id |
+------------+
| 0001546    |
| 0001660    |
| 0002207    |
| 0002349    |
| 0003123    |
| 0003208    |
| 0003319    |
| 0003811    |
| 0003837    |
| 0003842    |
+------------+`

10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: I'm [unable to replicate](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/068569/1/0) this problem, which suggests it's due to something you haven't shown us.  How/where are you executing those `select` statements/viewing the results?

Comment: Is student_import_record declared as an int?

Comment: ^A table declared as an int?

Comment: Sorry student_import_id

Comment: The table schema is missing. Also, what @eggyal mentioned - this appears to be due to something you haven't shown us. Are you running this query in MySQL terminal or from a program / programming language?

Comment: @JaredSol -- yes, student_import_id is an int

Comment: @N.B. -- it happens when I query from command line or using a tool such as SequelPro

Comment: Because you use in where clase compare against int. Try where student_import_id = "0000185". Also you could format your result using any text formater for mysql

Comment: Could you please include both `id` and `student_import_id` in the output of these two queries?  I'd like to verify that the records in each resultset are actually the same, and not different records that coincidentally have the same values for `student_id` but without the leading zeroes.

Comment: @eggyal - Thank you. That was it. So there must be an issue with how the data is getting persisted into the database for that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have already figured out what was going on. In the hope to close out this question, here's a link that explains type conversion in expression evaluation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type
>   conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions
>   occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to
>   strings as necessary, and vice versa.

```
mysql> SELECT 1+'1';
        -> 2
```

In your case, MySQL might be seeing arithmetic operation in the `WHERE` clause and performing implicit conversion to integers in that column. My recommendation is to structure the table, if possible, in a manner that numbers are in numeric column and non-numeric data is in its appropriate column. When there's mixed content, you could force the data to be character.